# Traefik v2 and Providers.Docker static configuration

Tags: traefik

I'm checking the new features of Traefik v2
And for some reason, I'm not able to set the Providers.Docker variables from the traefik toml conf.

The the values right under Providers are working, but Providers.Docker are ignored.

My toml sample file :

```
[Global]
  Debug = true
  CheckNewVersion = true
  SendAnonymousUsage = false

[API]
  Dashboard = true

[Providers]
  ProvidersThrottleDuration = 999
  [Providers.Docker]
    UseBindPortIP = true
```

From the logs, when Traefik start it dumps the static conf :

As you can see the Global,API, Providers are loaded, but Providers.Docker is ignored ?

Any clue what I'm doing wrong ?

```
time="2019-04-15T16:02:13Z" level=debug msg="Static configuration loaded 
{
    "Global": {
        "Debug": true,
        "CheckNewVersion": true,
        "SendAnonymousUsage": false
    },
    "ServersTransport": {
        "InsecureSkipVerify": false,
        "RootCAs": null,
        "MaxIdleConnsPerHost": 200,
        "ForwardingTimeouts": null
    },
    "EntryPoints": {
        "http": {
            "Address": ":80",
            "Transport": {
                "LifeCycle": {
                    "RequestAcceptGraceTimeout": 0,
                    "GraceTimeOut": 10000000000
                },
                "RespondingTimeouts": {
                    "ReadTimeout": 0,
                    "WriteTimeout": 0,
                    "IdleTimeout": 180000000000
                }
            },
            "ProxyProtocol": null,
            "ForwardedHeaders": {
                "Insecure": false,
                "TrustedIPs": null
            }
        },
        "traefik": {
            "Address": ":8080",
            "Transport": {
                "LifeCycle": {
                    "RequestAcceptGraceTimeout": 0,
                    "GraceTimeOut": 10000000000
                },
                "RespondingTimeouts": {
                    "ReadTimeout": 0,
                    "WriteTimeout": 0,
                    "IdleTimeout": 180000000000
                }
            },
            "ProxyProtocol": null,
            "ForwardedHeaders": {
                "Insecure": false,
                "TrustedIPs": null
            }
        }
    },
    "Providers": {
        "ProvidersThrottleDuration": 999000000000,
        "Docker": {
            "Constraints": null,
            "Watch": true,
            "Endpoint": "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
            "DefaultRule": "Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)",
            "TLS": null,
            "ExposedByDefault": true,
            "UseBindPortIP": false,
            "SwarmMode": false,
            "Network": "",
            "SwarmModeRefreshSeconds": 15
        },
        "File": null,
        "Marathon": null,
        "Kubernetes": null,
        "KubernetesCRD": null,
        "Rest": null
    },
    "API": {
        "EntryPoint": "traefik",
        "Dashboard": true,
        "Statistics": null,
        "Middlewares": null
    },
    "Metrics": null,
    "Ping": null,
    "Log": null,
    "AccessLog": null,
    "Tracing": null,
    "HostResolver": null,
    "ACME": null
}
```

My docker compose file :

```
version: '2'

networks:
  domain:
    external:
      name: domain

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    networks:
      - janier
    command: --api --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /etc/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml

  gogs:
    image: gogs/gogs
    networks:
      - domain
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.gogs.rule=Host(`gogs.domain`)"
      - "traefik.port=3000"
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker/volume/gogs:/data
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to the "command: --api --providers.docker"

The --providers.docker use the defaults, and Ignore the docker provider section of the toml configuration.